# in the apollo-client how I may be able to log or intercept all the operations (queries and mutations)

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

For analytic purposes I'd like to keep track on the client side of all the graphql operations (including ie `@client` ones). I was unable to find appropriate options in the API and wonder if this may be doable on the apollo-client level or may I need to introduce some proxy to intercept the calls by my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom Apollo link is a way to go.

You can use [`apollo-link-logger`](https://github.com/blackxored/apollo-link-logger) in particular to log all operations to console.

Usage (from docs):

```
import apolloLogger from 'apollo-link-logger';

// ...
ApolloLink.from([
  apolloLogger,
  // ...
]);
```

Note: Place `apolloLogger` before other links.

Output example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've checked this option and indeed this is the way to go. I was able do do a few liner `ApolloLink` to do a simple logging - even `@client` queries are being intercepted which is exaclty what I was looking for. I will soon complete the implementation. I think your answer is one to be accepted, I may provide my own answer showing the implementation still your proposal fully correct. Thanks!

Comment: @ciekawy Glad to hear.) I think it's worth emphasizing that links are chained and operations are passed through this chain. There are terminating and non-terminating links. `stateLink` and `HttpLink` are terminating. `stateLink` handles @client` operations and, as a result, they are not passed to the following links. You can check this by placing your logger link after `stateLink`. You'll notice that in this case `@client` operations are not logged anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer from Yuriy was exactly what I was looking for I marked is as accepted answer - Thanks!

Still for the record here is the code doing a job for me - I believe someone may find it useful, also it is worth to show it's simplicity.

It's worth noting that Apollo links are chainable - thus the argument to a link function are `operation: Operation` and `forward: NextLink` which is supposed to be called from our link implementation.

```
let analytics: Analytics; // this is Fabric.io Analytics to be provided by DI
const analyticsLink = new ApolloLink((
    operation: Operation,
    forward?: NextLink
) => {
    const operationType = operation.query.definitions[0].operation;
    return forward(operation)
        .map((result: FetchResult) => {
            try {
                analytics.sendCustomEvent(`${operationType}.${operation.operationName}`);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('analytics error', e);
            }
            return result;
        });
});
```

as a bonus we can also catch errors (i.e. to leverage fabric.io crashlytics) by using `apollo-link-error` (handling of errors in Apollo is a bit more complex);

```
const analyticsErrorLink = onError((error: ErrorResponse) => {
    try {
        // it's worth to rethink what we wanna log here
        const message = error.graphQLErrors ? error.graphQLErrors[0].message :
            (error.networkError.name + ': ' + error.networkError.message);
        analytics.sendNonFatalCrash('GraphQL error: ' + message);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('cannot report error to analytics', e);
    }
});
```

Finally to compose the links we should put our intercepting implementations at the beginning so we will be able to catch all the GraphQL operations including those marked with `@client` which are not reaching network link - in my case full link looks like:

```
ApolloLink.from([
    analyticsErrorLink,
    analyticsLink,
    stateLink,
    auth,
    http])
```